# Elastic Beanstalk, Docker and Continuous integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a beanstalk environment which use Docker.

Each time I push something, jenkins build and upload my new snapshot to S3. (I use S3 to store my version). Each version is a zip which contains my app and my Dockerfile.

Then I update my BS environment with the version I just uploaded.(BS create a new version with the version uploaded to S3, if the version exist it replace it, it usefull for snapshot).

Everything works fine the first time I deploy the version.
But when i do it a second time, it continue to works but it seems that my last version is not used. Docker not re build my freshly updated app.

Why this ? Did I missed something ? this is my [Dockefile](https://gist.github.com/agonist/1f0b6b09fbba240b56a8)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your link between S3 and your docker containers. How's your code moved ? Also are you deploying the docker container on EB or are you using a language specific deployment? ?

Comment: If you are deploying the docker container, EB can not detect the change. Because the Docker file does not change. The volumes mounted through VOLUME bypass the union file system. Changes there are invisible to EB

Comment: I updated the post to be more clear. So, how can I tell to EB my app has changed ?

Comment: But how the EB instance knows what is /root/wisdom and /repository on the instance. Are these relative to your build environment ? Or are these deployed on the EC2 instances? If the later, how? I still miss a piece here. Sorry

Comment: Another way to ask my question : where the container is built ? On the CI server or on the EB instances ?

Comment: http://blog.dooapp.com/2014/11/how-to-deploy-wisdom-application-to-aws.html this is exactly how my app is deployed jenkins just run the mvn -Pdeploy.  The container is built on the EB instance, when I create my environment I select Docker as predefined configuration. After that, BS do the necessary when you deploy a new version

Comment: Thank you I will have a look at that

Comment: @agonist_, can you send me in private a build log and/or your pom.xml file? I'm the author :)

Comment: Could you post to the mailing list as well? It helps to look. My guess is that it is related to environmentRef somehow :)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/beanstalker-users

Comment: I posted on the mailing list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it seems the update-environment call refuses to update a the same version number - and thats why we always rely on `${maven.build.timestamp}` and friends. Here's your retouched pom :]

Notice I'm using properties - Thats the suggested style for the latest version (oops, someone forgot to update the docs).

I've decided to try it with the latest 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT. Here's what you should add to your profile:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>awseb</id>
        <properties>
            <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>

            <beanstalker.region>eu-west-1</beanstalker.region>

            <beanstalk.applicationName>wisdom-demo</beanstalk.applicationName>

            <beanstalk.cnamePrefix>wisdom-demo</beanstalk.cnamePrefix>
            <beanstalk.environmentName>${beanstalk.cnamePrefix}</beanstalk.environmentName>
            <beanstalk.artifactFile>${project.basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}.zip</beanstalk.artifactFile>

            <beanstalk.environmentRef>${beanstalk.cnamePrefix}.elasticbeanstalk.com</beanstalk.environmentRef>

            <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
            <beanstalk.s3Key>apps/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${maven.build.timestamp}.zip</beanstalk.s3Key>
            <beanstalk.useLatestVersion>true</beanstalk.useLatestVersion>
            <beanstalk.versionLabel>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${maven.build.timestamp}</beanstalk.versionLabel>

            <beanstalk.applicationHealthCheckURL>/ping</beanstalk.applicationHealthCheckURL>

            <beanstalk.instanceType>m1.small</beanstalk.instanceType>
            <beanstalk.keyName>aldrin@leal.eng.br</beanstalk.keyName>
            <beanstalk.iamInstanceProfile>aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role</beanstalk.iamInstanceProfile>
            <beanstalk.solutionStack>64bit Amazon Linux 2014.* running Docker 1.*</beanstalk.solutionStack>
            <beanstalk.environmentType>SingleInstance</beanstalk.environmentType>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>br.com.ingenieux</groupId>
                    <artifactId>beanstalk-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-deploy</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>upload-source-bundle</goal>
                                <goal>create-application-version</goal>
                                <goal>put-environment</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

From the example above, just tweak your cnamePrefix and the latest three properties. Here's a rundown:

## So if you want to deploy, simply:

$ mvn -Pawseb deploy

## Or, if you want to boot it

from scratch the latest version (thus using useLatestVersion) once deployed, simply do:

$ mvn -Pawseb -Dbeanstalk.versionLabel= beanstalk:create-environment

By setting to blank the versionLabel, it effectively activates the useLatestVersion behaviour: When there isn't a version, use the latest one.

## Oh, a deployment failed?

Easy peasy:

$ mvn -Pawseb beanstalk:rollback-version

Comment: I finnaly choose the timestamp solution it probably the best to do. I configuree my pom as you do and it works fine, so thanks you for help. Will you release 1.4.0 soon ?

Comment: In fact it works with 1.3.5 - Except for .artifactFile which was just added :)

Comment: One more thing: If you're on anything other than eu-central-1, you could use git incremental deployment, which makes the configuration easier (sorta of) and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your explanation and the link to the blog post.
I follow these step by step instructions and successfully deployed my first Wisdom application in a Docker container on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

[image]

I then upgrade the Java source code, compiled with `mvn package`, tested locally and deployed again the new ZIP file using AWS Console.

My AWS Elastic BeansTalk environment was correctly updated.

[image]

So, it looks like the deployment problem you are observing is lying in the [maven AWS Elastic Beanstalk plugin](https://github.com/ingenieux/beanstalker) that deploys the code. 
Manual deploys work correctly.  Since this maven plugin is a third-party, open-source project, I am not the right person to investigate this.  I would suggest you to contact the project maintainer and / or open an issue in their [Issue Tracking System](https://github.com/ingenieux/beanstalker/issues)

As a workaround, you can deploy manually (or script this procedure from your CI/CD environment) :

1. Copy your artefact to your AWS Elastic Beanstalk bucket

`aws s3 --region <REGION_NAME> cp ./target/YOUR_ARTIFACTID-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip s3://<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>/20141128-210900-YOUR_ARTIFACTID-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip`

2. Create an application version with your zip file

`aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --region <REGION_NAME> --application-name <YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME> --version-label 20141128-212100 --source-bundle S3Bucket=<YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>,S3Key=20141128-210900-YOUR_ARTIFACTID-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip`

3. Deploy that version

`aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --region <YOUR_REGION_NAME> --environment-name <YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_NAME> --version-label 20141128-212100`

These three steps might be automated from maven or jenkins, I will let you this as an exercise :-)

Comment: Cool thank's for your great answer, I'll try this soon and give you back my return.

Comment: Hey @Stormacq, let me look into it :)

Comment: It seems to work if the application version have a different name, but if you upload 1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip create deploy it as version 1.0-SNAPSHOT, and delete this version then create it again with same name, it's not working

Comment: following to my last comment I precise that it's not working from the AWS console and from the plugin. Maybe it's the normal behavior

Comment: thats because you were using the same version number - the API rejects updates when its the same version. Plus, upload-source-bundle refuses to upload anything which doesn't resemble a .zip file, so perhaps there are some mismatches. Anyway, I 'just' retouched your profile and I'm publishing it.